# Cannot terminate or close a PDO connection MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

The page seems to continue loading indefinitely event when the script reaches the end. How can I terminate the connection after breaking out of the PHP loop? I have set the $pdo and $usearch variables to null and reviewed other questions.

```
<?php
            
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname", 'user', 'pass');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, false);
$sql = "SELECT `counter` FROM `table` WHERE `country` LIKE 'United States'";

$start = microtime(true);

$uresult = $pdo->query($sql);
if ($uresult) {
while ($row = $uresult->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

$elapsed = microtime(true) - $start; 

if ($elapsed > 3){
    echo "took more than 3 seconds";
    break;
}
}
}

echo "done";
$uresult = null;
$pdo=null;
?>
```

Comment: Sorry, typo, altering now.

Comment: $pdo=null; this should end the connection right? Is there some other way to prevent it loading data when the script reaches the end. Help definitely appreciated.

Comment: Yes, `$pdo = null;` closes the connection. What makes you say that PDO is to blame for your browser not ending the page download? Do you ever see the messages _"took more than 3 seconds"_ or _"done"_?

Comment: Yes, I see both those messages, but the browser continues loading. If not PDO then what?

Comment: You shouldn't guess what the cause is. If you do you basically admit you don't know. You could, for instance, test the page without the `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, false);` line. If it finishes then, but not when the line is there, then you have an argument that the unbuffered query is to blame. Remember that buffered queries are the norm.

Comment: The problem that the browser tries to load the page seemingly indefinitely definitely has nothing to do with the code shown. If the last echo output can be seen in the browser, the PHP script has long since ended. Or does the script run in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved to MySQLi:

```
$mysqli  = new mysqli("localhost", "", "", "");
$uresult = $mysqli->query($sql, MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);  
$start = microtime(true);

if ($uresult) {
while ($row = $uresult->fetch_assoc()) {
$num++;
echo $num;
$elapsed = microtime(true) - $start;    
if ($elapsed  > 20){ 
echo "More than 20 seconds";    
break;    
}
}
}

$mysqli->close();
```